# pagination with filter knp paginator

Tags: symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I am trying to filter with the help of pagination. when I try and do that the first page is okay when I click to go in the second page it shows the initial result so without any filter. they are both placed in the same route the filter and the display
this is my controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function home(Request $request)
        {
            $property = new Property();

            $searchForm = $this->createFormBuilder($property)
                ->add('type', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Type::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                ])
                ->add('filter', SubmitType::class, [
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'btn btn-outline-dark btn-rounded waves-effect'
                    ]
                ])
                ->getForm();

            $searchForm -> handleRequest($request);

            if ($searchForm->isSubmitted() && $searchForm->isValid()){
                $type = $searchForm->get('type')->getData();

                $search = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Property::class)->findByType($type);
                if (count($type) == 0) {
                    $search = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Property::class)->findBy(['isSold' => 0]);
                }

            } else {
                $search = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Property::class)->findBy(['isSold' => 0]);
            }

            $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
            $result = $paginator->paginate(
                $search,
                $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
                $request->query->getInt('limit', 10)
            );

            }

            return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
                'property' => $result,
                'searchForm' => $searchForm->createView(),
                'propertyCountByType' => $propertyCountByType,

            ]);
        }
```

here is the query in the repository:

```
public function findByType($type){
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->andWhere('p.type IN (:type)')
            ->andWhere('p.isSold = 0')
            ->setParameter('type', $type)
            ->getQuery();
        return $query->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on my own . `->setMethod('GET')` made the difference.

```
$searchForm = $this->createFormBuilder($property)
            ->add('type', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Type::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'mapped' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => false,
            ])
            ->add('filter', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-outline-dark btn-rounded waves-effect'
                ]
            ])
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->getForm();
```

Comment: Such a simple thing, but I missed it in the documentation. Thanks for pointing out we explicitly need to use GET.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you execute the query (its actually strange that the paginator doesnt complain about that...there should be an error like "Expecting type query, got ArrayCollection" or something like that.

The paginator expects that you pass a `Query` object, then the paginator will "extend" that query with `setMaxResults` and `setFirstResult`, depending on the parameters from the request.

When you fire `findBy` or your `findByType`, the result is an `ArrayCollection`, so at that point its already "too late" to paginate.

Maybe im missing something here, can you double check that the code that you provided is really "working, but not as-expected"?

Comment: its working fine the only problem is as I mentioned above when I press the button to move to the second page of the result it disables the filter